# MySQL delete selected rows from table

Tags: mysql

Ok so I am a bit stumped. I am horrible with the command line. I have a Database with a table "wp_postmeta" that has 2 million extra/empty entries. These got there from a malfunctioning plugin. I am using SSH to access my db and this `SQL` query does not seem to work. I am trying to delete only the entries that have a `meta_key` value that starts with `'_oembed'`. Here is what I used:

```
DELETE * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE  ('%_oembed%');
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to find things that start with `_oembed` then you should remove the `%` before it, otherwise you'll end up matching things with that string in the middle, like `123_oembed`.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like my lack of patience proceeds me... Right after I posted this, I checked back to my SSH and it had successfully executed the query. It just took a few minutes!

Comment: `DELETE` operations on large tables can take significant time. Be careful when doing this on a production server.